# Show latest comments (sitewide) in CakePHP - what's the proper way?

Tags: php, cakephp

I need to have a sitewide sidebar which will contain 5 latest comments to articles.
Should I use elements with requestAction + cache in default layout or it can be achieved in more simple way?
I use CakePHP 2.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no need to use requestAction, simply put your code in your `AppController`'s `beforeFilter` method, then put your sidebar in your layout.

Comment: you mean beforeRender. beforeFilter is not supposed to be used to pass stuff down to the view. typical beginners mistake.

Comment: No, I mean `beforeFilter`. I'd love to see your source that says `beforeFilter` isn't supposed to be used to pass data to the view.

Comment: you do you that beforeFilter is not triggered on error pages for example? that makes the variables unrelyable in the views/layout. only beforeRender is always triggered and therefore should be used for passing down variables that need to be used int he view. ALSO beforeRender() often doesnt get invoked in actions (PRG redirects etc - we don't render the view but redirect first). so you create lots of overhead doing sth for the view so early (you will never need those then as the view is never rendered here). its like rendering the template in the bootstrap. it just doesnt make any sense.

Comment: @mark what do you suggest me to do? Should I go for requestAction or use Hoff's solution or you can suggest more best practice way?

Comment: @mark You make a good point. Although I use a custom exception renderer that does call my `beforeFilter` on error pages so my variables do still get passed to the view. @user1604153 you still use the same solution just use the `beforeRender` callback in your `AppController` instead of `beforeFilter`. Both callbacks will do what you want, one is just a little more efficient than the other.

Comment: @user1604153 just use the AppController's beforeRender() and you will be fine. Either way: dont use request action!

Comment: @mark So if I understand you right I need to 1. Load model(s) that I need using loadModel(); and when I pass fetched data to the view? And if I need to use many different tables/models I should go with the same approach (loadModel + beforeRender)? Will my controllers that already use some of models be fine when I add loadModel (with the same model(s)) to AppController?

Comment: yes, that should be fine. if you want to make sure: if (!isset()) {loadModel}